# what are the valid values for 'runner' in wdio.conf.js file?

Tags: webdriver-io, wdio-v5

for Webdriver.io what other values can runner take in wdio.conf.js besides runner: 'local'? Any examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found out from the official WDIO chat that only local is supported for now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps such an example will help you?from my work example

```
exports.config = {
  hostname: "some-test",
  port: 4444,
  path: "/wd/hub",
  specs: ["./tests/*.ts"],
  sync: true,
  services: ["selenium-standalone"],
  capabilities: [
    {
      browserName: "chrome"
    }
  ],
  baseUrl: "http://my-url",
  framework: "mocha",
  mochaOpts: {
    ui: "bdd",
    timeout: 10000
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks but, really it was only about `runner: 'local'`. And found out as mentioned in the comment above that at this moment only `local` option is supported.